# d3 javascript clicking a line to change line color - changes all lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force-directed graph and want to change the color of a line between 2 nodes when I click on the line. However, the following code changes the color of all the lines, not just the one I clicked.

My css for the line and the clicked line are:

```
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link--clicked {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I call a function when clicking on the line using:

```
var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
    .on("click", function(d) { edge_clicked(d); });

function edge_clicked(d) {    
  d3.select("path").classed("link--clicked", false); //remove color class of any previously clicked link
  var clicked = d3.select(this); //select clicked element
  path.classed("link--clicked", true); //set class of clicked link
}
```

I suspect it has to do with how I am calling the path.classed command which affects all paths/lines not just the clicked line. However, I can't figure out the syntax for the selected line.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is the use of `this`. Inside the function edge_clicked, `this` points to the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), not the clicked element.

To solve this, first we pass that clicked element to the function edge_clicked:

```
var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
    .on("click", function(d) { edge_clicked(this);});
```

So, we don't need `this` anymore inside the function edge_clicked.

Now we change the function:

```
function edge_clicked(elem) {    
    d3.selectAll(".link").classed("link--clicked", false);//selectAll instead of select
    var clicked = d3.select(elem);
    clicked.classed("link--clicked", true);//set class of clicked link
}
```

Notice that we firs select All (not `select`) links, and then we select only the clicked one.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfect. I appreciate the detail on scoping and selectAll.

Answer (score 2):

The main shortcomings have already been addressed by Gerardo Furtado in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38987123/4235784), namely the scope issue and the lack of using `selectAll`. Although Gerardo's answer is correct, I think taking a different approach might clean up code and mind.

There is no need to have an anonymous function as the handler for the click event which will do nothing more than call yet another function. Passing in your function `edge_clicked` directly as the event handler will solve the scope issue.

```
var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
        .on("click", edge_clicked);      // Just pass in the handler function
```

In this case within the handler function `this` will refer to the element clicked. Personally, I would also choose a different implementation for this function which looks cleaner and should run slightly faster because only one selection is needed instead of two:

```
function edge_clicked() {    
  var clicked = this;         // Remember the element clicked upon
  d3.selectAll("path").classed("link--clicked", function() {
    return clicked === this;  // Assign class for clicked element, else unassign class
  });
}
```

This will use a closure to save the value of `this`, i.e. the clicked element, in `clicked` to make it available in the callback to `.classed()`. It then selects and iterates over all `path`s assigning the class only to the `clicked` element while unassigning it for any other element.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I checked Gerardo Furtado as he was first to respond and addressed the major problem with my approach (scope and selectAll).

Comment: @JeffA I am fine with that. It's your question and you are free to accept whatever answer helped you the most. Gerardo did a good job pointing out the errors and he presented a solution working perfectly. My own answer is more of an alternative showing how these pitfalls could be avoided by streamlining the code.